# Noun phrases and which/where

Tags: noun-phrases

does a noun phrase followed by a 'which' or 'where' clause form another noun phrase?

example 1:

> *The fast car which fly's

In this case, does  'The fast car which fly's'  form a noun phase?

My intuition tells me 'yes', because it can be followed by a main verb

example 2:

> nice houses where constructed

Comment: Why do you have a possessive 's' after fly?

Comment: @marcellothearcane  No reason,  coudnt think of a better example.

Comment: Yes, it forms a noun phrase. (It doesn't form *another* noun phrase, however.  There is only one noun phrase there.)

Comment: Both your examples are meaningless as written. Presumably you mean that the car _flies_.